# PHP associative array syntax with JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative

this is a two part question. First, I have code to make a call to `graph.facebook.com` with parameters that the user can enter. This returns a json when called.

**The code is below:**

```
$RAW_DATA = json_decode(file_get_contents($URL_FINAL));
```

If I go to the URL in my browser everything is fairly organized but if I use a `var_dump()` it looks like there are extra fields not shown in the browser, is there something wrong with my decoding or is it `var_dump()` showing things that I don't see on my browser?

Second, after retrieving the JSON trying to access the subfields of data within it have proven to be problem.

**For example:**

```
     {
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "11111111_111111111",
         "from": {
            "name": "John",
            "id": "111111111"
         },
         "story": "John shared We Are Change's photo.",
         "picture": "http://photos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/35552_10151311513538690_352701444_s.jpg",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151311513538690&set=a.10150159213018690.338979.86518833689&type=1",
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "caption": "Happy election day everybody!",
         "properties": [
            {
               "name": "By",
               "text": "We Are Change",
               "href": "http://www.facebook.com/WeAreChange.org?ref=stream"
            }
         ] 
}
```

This is what the URL returns, how would I pull just the 'story' from this?

I have tried several different syntax styles but the only one that returns anything is `$RAW_DATA->{'data'};` and this just prints 'Array'. As soon as I try to go into the next layer I can't get anything to print.

Comment: Look at the [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) documentation for examples of its typical output. Paste your json into http://array.include-once.org/ to see how to traverse it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, using that made it much easier to understand and being able to mouse over different values to see their paths was very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because "data" is an array of objects (or associative arrays).

```
$RAW_DATA->{'data'}[0];
```

Would work if you always knows it only has one element, otherwise you should loop through $RAW_DATA->{'data'}.

Or to simplify:

```
$RAW_DATA['data'][0]['story']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var_dump($RAW_DATA['data']);
var_dump($RAW_DATA['data']['id']);
```

this treats $RAW_DATA as an array, and will work.

$RAW_DATA->data will treat it as an object, and will fail.